# Implementing a sorting method similar to bubble sort

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

I am trying to figure out how to implement a sorting method that is like bubble sort but differs in some ways.

The pseudo code would be like this:

1. Get list and take first element in the list
2. if the element next to it is smaller then swap the elements
3. else mark the element as moved and repeat until all elements are marked

Here is how I thought about implementing this problem:

```
sortElement [] elm= []
sortElement [x] elm= [x]
sortElement lis@(x:y:xs) elm = 
--first if is to find the element in the list that i want to move
if elm /=x  
then x:sortElement(y:xs) elm 
else if x > y then y:sortElement(x:xs) elm 
else lis

stackBubble lis = stackBubble' lis lis

stackBubble' [] [] = [] 
stackBubble' [x] [] = [x]
stackBubble' [] [x] = []
stackBubble' lis@(x:xs) lis1@(x1:xs1) = do 

sortElement(stackBubble' lis xs1) x1
```

The error I am getting is

> Non-exhaustive patterns in function stackBubble'

If I do like suggested elsewhere:

```
sortElement(x:stackBubble' xs xs1) x1
```

I get a fully sorted list after one iteration when I would like to get something like this:

```
[4,2,7,1] => iterating 4 [2,4,7,1], after iterating all the elements [2,4,1,7].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this would probably be using guards and simple recursion, for example:

```
bubble :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
bubble (x:y:xs) | x > y = y : bubble (x : xs)
                | otherwise = x : bubble (y : xs)
bubble x = x
```

Have you covered guards yet? Just in case you haven't, I'll explain in short. The syntax for a guard is

```
| (expression that evaluates to Bool) = code
```

Just like in pattern matching Haskell will check the guards from top to bottom and execute the first one that returns true. `otherwise` is the "fall-through case" which is just defined as `True`.

So going through the code line by line:

```
bubble (x:y:xs) | x > y = y : bubble (x : xs)
```

We separate the list into x:y:xs and run the first guard which checks if y is smaller than x, if it is y is appended to the result list we're building and bubble is called again with (x : xs).

```
                | otherwise = x : bubble (y : xs)
```

Second guard always returns True, keeps x at it's position and calls bubble again with the list still in the same order.
The last line just returns the last element, or in case you call the function with an empty list, an empty list.

Assuming the example list [4,2,5,1] the execution would work like this:

```
1: 2 is smaller than 4 -> 2 : bubble [4,5,1]
2: 5 is not smaller than 4 -> 2 : 4 : bubble [5,1]
3: 1 is smaller than 5 -> 2 : 4 : 1 : bubble [5]
4: end of list -> 2 : 4 : 1 : 5 -> [2,4,1,5]
```

This implementation has no explicit "marking" an element as moved but that's not required.

Comment: Ok this works, is this the same as saying : bubble' lis@(x:y:xs) = if x > y then y:bubble' (x:xs) else x: bubble(y:xs) . I had already tried that guess I did not reload in my console before testing. But thank you, I guess my later approaches were a bit of an overkill.

Comment: Yes it is. Oh and by the way, there's no need to do `lis@(x:y:xs)` just the part in the brackets is enough. Otherwise you assign the entire list to `lis` without ever using it. GHC can warn you about such things if you run it with -Wall

Comment: Thank you for the -Wall command, using it right now. Thank you for your help, it was priceless.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because `stackBubble'` doesn't specify the result when one argument is empty and the other has more than one element.

Comment: Yes you are right thanks. After I fixed it my code still always returns ordered list, do you see some errors at a quick glance? What I am trying to accomplish is if I have a list [4,2,5,1] then the program would call sortMe with a list and a element to sort until lis1 is empty so the list [4,2,5,1] would turn into [2,4,1,5]. Thank you for the catch

Answer (score 2):

I began to code a corrected version, but while I was doing that the question was answered. I'll include it here anyway for the sake of demonstration:

```
bubbleSort l =
  bSort l []
  where bSort []        acc = acc
        bSort [x]       acc = acc ++ [x]
        bSort (x:y:xys) acc
          | x > y     = bSort (acc ++ (y:x:xys)) []
          | otherwise = bSort (y:xys) (acc ++ [x])
```

Note that this is probably grossly inefficient even by the standards of bubble sort because of all the list concatenation (it would most likely be preferable to append to the head of the accumulator list and then reverse when necessary). This implementation is extremely naive, but reasonably concise and perhaps instructive, though more because of the blatancy of its crudeness than any positive virtue.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I am dealing with a sorting method that is like bubble sort but not exactly like it. It bubbles each element (starting at element 0) just ones  for example [3,4,2,1,7] would return [3,1,2,4,7].